# How to set different Background Image For Grouped Table Section..?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Hi i am trying to set image for Background of Grouped Table-view Section's (Not for Section Header) i am using following code:-

```
-(void)addBackgroundViewForSectionIndex:(int)tagIndex {

    for (UIView * subview in tbl_home.subviews) {
        if(subview.tag == tagIndex)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect sectionFrame = [tbl_home rectForSection:tagIndex];
    UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:sectionFrame];
    newView.tag = tagIndex;
    [newView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Section@2x.png"]];
    [tbl_home addSubview:newView];
    [tbl_home sendSubviewToBack:newView];

}
```

That set Image as a background but there is problem some cell is not display or `newView` over some cell.

i would like to set image like the below screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: nitin give me one sample code i will do it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some change now help with this code i successfully set the image as above image using this code:-

```
-(void)addBackgroundViewForSectionIndex:(int)tagIndex {

    for (UIView * subview in tbl_home.subviews) {
        if(subview.tag == tagIndex)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect sectionFrame = [tbl_home rectForSection:tagIndex];
    UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:sectionFrame];
    newView.tag = tagIndex;
    [newView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Section@2x.png"]];
    [tbl_home addSubview:newView];
    [tbl_home sendSubviewToBack:newView];

}
```

previouselly i call this method in to `cellForRowIndex` so that called every time and create problem. Now i call this method in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

like bellow and working fine now:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self addBackgroundViewForSectionIndex:indexPath.section];
}
```